# How to make a date object in java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-test

So I am making a unit test where I test the date I get from my database. The problem is that I cannot seem to get the date that I want to make in my unit test properly formatted.
The error will make my problem more clear:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<2021-04-05 00:00:00.0> but was:<Mon Apr 05 00:00:00 CEST 2021>
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
```

**This is the test method:**

```
@Test
void whenSaveResult_thenCorrectResultSaved() throws ParseException {
    // given
    var inputString = "2021-04-05 00:00:00.0";
    DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
    Date date = inputFormat.parse(inputString);

    var input = ResultDto.builder()
            .name("Fontys Result")
            .date(date)
            .build();

    // when
    resultService.saveResult(input);

    var createdResult = em.createQuery("SELECT l FROM Result l WHERE l.name = 'Fontys Result' ", Result.class).setMaxResults(1).getSingleResult();


    // then
    Assert.assertEquals(createdResult.getName(), "Fontys Result");
    Assert.assertEquals(createdResult.getDate(), date);
}
```

How can I format the date properly so that it matches the expected result?
Thanks!

As requested the Result class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "result")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Result {
    public Result(Integer id, Date date,  String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.date = date;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Date date;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "result", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private Set<PartyResultUser> partyResultUsers;

    public Result() {

    }
}
```

Comment: you have a correct date object. What you are trying to compare, are formatted dates, Strings which are formatted. Your expected and your actual don't match, so either change your expected, or change the formatting returned by the method you test

Comment: How do I change the the value of the inputFormat so that it lookes like this: 2021-04-05 00:00:00.0

Comment: in your test, you perform a formatting, do you perform the same formatting in your getDate() method of your 'createdResult'? try and print this: System.out.println(createdResult.getDate()); before your assert. Either that, or your date variable should be formatted correctly.

Comment: No it just gets the date from the database which is formatted like this 2021-04-05 00:00:00.0

Comment: Can you share the Result class with us?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use an appropriate class from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It also seems that you’ve got an object that is really a `java.sql.Timestamp`, that is no good either.

Comment: Don’t handle and compare your dates and times as strings. Get the date and time as an `OffsetDateTime` or `LocalDateTIme` from the database (depending on SQL data type) and compare it with an object of the same type in Java. Just like you compare numbers as `int` vlaues and don’t need to worry whether strings `"7"` and `"07"` are equal.

Comment: Would your share your `Result` class and your database table schema, please?

Answer (score 0):

Aside:
Date is a terrible class and was replaced by classes in the java.time.* packages starting in (or around) Java 8.

That said,
here is some code to get a `Date` from an `OffsetDateTime`

```
        Date actualDate;
        OffsetDateTime testOffsetDateTime;

        testOffsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.now()
            .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS)
            .withYear(2021)
            .withMonth(4)
            .withDayOfMonth(5);

        actualDate = new Date(testOffsetDateTime.toInstant().toEpochMilli());
```

After that code executes,
the `actualDate` variable will contain a real `Date` value.
Do with it as you wish.

Note:
this is not the "best" way to achieve your desired goal,
but it is a functional way to achieve your goal.

Finally,
this is unlikely to solve your problem.
Until you include the `ResultDto` class in the question,
we are unlikely to identify the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

In `Assert.assertEquals`, if parameters are Object then `Object.toString()` is used for comparison. In your case `date` is an `Object`, so `Assert.assertEquals` compares `date.toString()` with `createdResult.getDate()`. As it is written in [the oracle offical document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString()) `toString()` method for `Date` returns `String` with the format `dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy`. In your case `var inputString = "2021-04-05 00:00:00.0"` is converted to `Mon Apr 05 00:00:00 CEST 2021`. Instead of using `Assert.assertEquals(createdResult.getDate(), date)` use one of these

> `Assert.assertEquals(createdResult.getDate(), inputFormat.format(date))`

or

> `Assert.assertEquals(createdResult.getDate(), inputString)`

Comment: But createdResult.getDate() is also a Date and should be converted to the same string. Or does the createdResult returns an sql.Date?

Comment: Maybe it is formatted String, if @LardinoisJosse shares us the Result class, we can find the best solution. And as you written it can be sql.Date

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with the help of the people that answered my post:

**My service class:**

```
 @Test
    void whenSaveResult_thenCorrectResultSaved() throws ParseException {

        // given
        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of(2021, 04,05);

        var input = ResultDto.builder()
                .name("Fontys Result")
                .date(localDate)
                .build();

        // when
        resultService.saveResult(input);

        var createdResult = em.createQuery("SELECT l FROM Result l WHERE l.name = 'Fontys Result' ", Result.class).setMaxResults(1).getSingleResult();


        // then
        Assert.assertEquals(createdResult.getName(), "Fontys Result");
        Assert.assertEquals(createdResult.getDate(), localDate);
    }
```

**My result class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "result")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Result {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private LocalDate date;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "result", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private Set<PartyResultUser> partyResultUsers;
    
}
```